# Multiple Browsers on Mac

Tags: browsers, safari

Can I keep Tor and another browser on my Mac i.e. Safari so I can use the other browser to see videos (Flash?)

Comment: A similar question was also answered here: http://tor.stackexchange.com/q/921/88

Comment: Do you want the other (non-tor) browser communicate over the Tor network?

Answer (score 1):

Tor Browser can run alongside any number of other browsers, but by default your other browsers will not be run through the Tor network. Many users have Tor Browser for private browsing whilst keeping other browsing for less sensitive use.